# Cloud Firestore better structure for the case

Tags: database, firebase, data-structures, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I am developing an APP where the users (firebase auth) will register their expenses and will be notified (OneSignal) on each Sunday about the expenses that will expire in the week.
My firestore structure is:

```
-users (collection)
---xxXXxxX (user document)
-----email
-----OneSignal ID
-----expenses (collection)
-------yyYYYyY (expense document)
---------dueDate
---------value
---------userId
-------aaAAaaA (expense document)
---------dueDate
---------value
---------userId
---bBBbbBB (another user document)
-----email
-----OneSignal ID
-----expenses (collection)
-------wwWWwwW (expense document)
---------dueDate
(...)
```

Based on this structure, every Sunday Google Cloud will run a schedule function that will query all the expenses that expire in the week (Collection group query - returning a list of expenses that can have more than one expense per user.)

With this list, still in function, I will separate manually the userId from expenses, creating a second list with one register per user. With the second list the function will get the OneSignal ID of each user (another queries on firebase, one per user in the list) and register a notification in OneSignal service for every user.

P.S: OneSignal ID can change, because this situation i can't save the OneSignalID on expense.

I guess that this structure will work, but appears that this is not the best solution because many queries running on the "background" and this can be costly in the future.

Does anyone have a better suggestion for this case? Maybe another structure on firestore...

I hope that I explained the "problem" well. English is not my first language.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

From what I've read in the documentation, you're doing perfect, and here's why (anyone, correct me if I'm wrong)

1. Firebase charges you when the users download more than Xgb of data. As far as I know you won't be charged for doing queries and filtering. So you're good in this aspect.
2. The Firebase firestore querying time depends solely on the amount of results you get. Doesn't matter the structure. So if you're fine with this structure, stick with it. I see no problem at all.

EDIT : I just re-read the docs and found this:

> When you use Cloud Firestore, you are charged for the following:
>
> - The number of reads, writes, and deletes that you perform.
> - The amount of storage that your database uses, including overhead for metadata and indexes.
> - The amount of network bandwidth that you use.

So you will be charged when querying apparently. In this case a better way to structure the db would be to flattening the expenses tree maybe. You could have something like this

```
Users - - - -
             |------
             |------

Expenses - - - - -
                     user ID - - -
                      Etc---------
                      Etc----------
```

This way you could filter for a user's query.
[https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#:~:text=Cloud%20Firestore%20provides%20powerful%20query,Data%20and%20Get%20Realtime%20Updates](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/query-data/queries#:%7E:text=Cloud%20Firestore%20provides%20powerful%20query,Data%20and%20Get%20Realtime%20Updates).

Comment: In reality, firebase charges for the number of reads, edits, deletes and stored data. [https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing#us]. This is one of the reasons why I want to avoid searching for all user expenses to send just one notification. But I can't see how ...

Comment: I just updated my answer. What I meant is that you could make another collection just for expenses? And write the users ID as a document or as the ID itself. That would save you some reads

Comment: Thank you @Agustin . I understand your suggestion but i don't see how the solution will save some reads, because it seems to me that I will still need to read all expenses by user in the week (returning many expenses for user, if he has) and after get the OnSignal ID for each user based on Users collections, right?

Comment: Just for complement, with collection group [https://firebase.googleblog.com/2019/06/understanding-collection-group-queries.html] I can filter all expense by user too. I think it's basically the same result that you has mentioned, right?

Comment: Yes :) I think you could save some reads laying it more flat, but not much honestly.  I'm not seeing any bigger improvement for this, sorry! You're just going to have to wait til a firestore pro gives you a hint.